# Does Prolog use Eager Evaluation?

Tags: prolog, lazy-evaluation

Because Prolog uses chronological backtracking(from the Prolog Wikipedia page) even after an answer is found(in this example where there can only be one solution), would this justify Prolog as using eager evaluation?

```
mother_child(trude, sally).

father_child(tom, sally).
father_child(tom, erica).
father_child(mike, tom).

sibling(X, Y)      :- parent_child(Z, X), parent_child(Z, Y).

parent_child(X, Y) :- father_child(X, Y).
parent_child(X, Y) :- mother_child(X, Y).
```

With the following output:

```
?- sibling(sally, erica).
true ;
false.
```

Comment: The question seems to be incomplete. What is the "this case" mentioned? What is meant by "chronological backtracking"?

Comment: Added example from Wikipedia

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To summarize the discussion with @WillNess below, **yes, Prolog is strict.** However, Prolog's execution model and semantics are substantially different from the languages that are usually labelled strict or non-strict. For more about this, see below.

---

I'm not sure the question really applies to Prolog, because it doesn't really have the kind of implicit evaluation ordering that other languages have. Where this really comes into play in a language like Haskell, you might have an expression like:

```
f (g x) (h y)
```

In a strict language like ML, there is a defined evaluation order: `g x` will be evaluated, then `h y`, and `f (g x) (h y)` last. In a language like Haskell, `g x` and `h y` will only be evaluated as required ("non-strict" is more accurate than "lazy"). But in Prolog,

```
f(g(X), h(Y))
```

does not have the same meaning, because it isn't using a function notation. The query would be broken down into three parts, `g(X, A)`, `h(Y, B)`, and `f(A,B,C)`, and those constituents can be placed in any order. The evaluation strategy *is* strict in the sense that what comes earlier in a sequence *will* be evaluated before what comes next, but it is non-strict in the sense that there is no requirement that variables be instantiated to ground terms before evaluation can proceed. Unification is perfectly content to complete without having given you values for every variable. I am bringing this up because you have to break down a complex, nested expression in another language into several expressions in Prolog.

Backtracking has nothing to do with it, as far as I can tell. I don't think backtracking to the nearest choice point and resuming from there precludes a non-strict evaluation method, it just happens that Prolog's is strict.

Comment: `A=p(B)` is a perfectly fine Prolog value. `A=B` is a perfectly fine Prolog value, and even `A=A` is so too. :) You over-complicate things here, Daniel, :) trying to reflect on the "functional" code of which a Prolog code is "an expression of". Prolog stands in its own right; Prolog is a strict programming language. It has some explicit delaying through `freeze`, but sans that, it's just plain strict. That its data are by default symbolic, is an orthogonal issue. Yes it's easy to build a goal to be called later, but when we call it, we get result back - all of it. Free logvars and all. :)

Comment: i.e., let's take `maplist` for an example.

Comment: @WillNess I suppose you're right, but I think Prolog is odd enough, and the OP is confused enough, that it's worth digging into the mire and trying to clarify. Saying "Prolog is strict" is true, but without any reflection on how very different Prolog is from other languages it may leave the OP more confused, or worse, with a false certainty of a misapprehension. I cannot guarantee I've helped. :) But I think between all of us clarity can be had.

Comment: You're right about the unusual and confusing nature of Prolog's data to a non-initiated. I just think we ought to strive for precision in our language when matters are confusing enough on their own. I'm not seeking to disprove your answer in any way, just to fine tune. :) For instance, your statement "Unification is perfectly content to complete without having given you values for every variable." seems potentially confusing to me; it is what I responded to. :) But hopefully

Comment: @WillNess I have edited the answer to get the point sooner, and make what was there before a discussion, which I have lightly edited.

Answer (score 5):

That Prolog pauses after giving each of the several correct answers to a problem has nothing to do with laziness; it is a part of its user interaction protocol. Each answer is calculated eagerly.

Sometimes there will be only one answer but Prolog doesn't know that in advance, so it waits for us to press `;` to continue search, in hopes of finding another solution. Sometimes it is able to deduce it in advance and will just stop right away, but only sometimes.

*update:*

Prolog does no evaluation on its own. All terms are unevaluated, as if "quoted" in Lisp.

Prolog will unfold your predicate definitions as written and is perfectly happy to keep your data structures full of <s>unevaluated</s> uninstantiated holes, if so entailed by your predicate definitions.

Haskell does not need any values, a *user* does, when requesting an output.

Similarly, Prolog produces solutions one-by-one, as per the user requests.

Prolog can even be seen to be lazier than Haskell where all arithmetic is strict, i.e. immediate, whereas in Prolog you have to explicitly request the arithmetic evaluation, with `is/2`.

So perhaps the question is ill-posed. Prolog's operations model is just *too different*. There are no "results" nor "functions", for one; but viewed from another angle, everything is a result, and predicates are "multi"-functions.

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, the question is not correct in what it states. Chronological backtracking **does not mean** that Prolog will necessarily backtrack "in an example where there can be only one solution".

Consider this:

```
foo(a, 1).
foo(b, 2).
foo(c, 3).

?- foo(b, X).
X = 2.

?- foo(X, 2).
X = b.
```

So this is an example that does have only one solution and Prolog recognizes that, and does not attempt to backtrack. There are cases in which you can implement a solution to a problem in a way that Prolog will *not recognize* that there is only one logical solution, but this is due to the implementation and is not inherent to Prolog's execution model.

You should read up on Prolog's execution model. From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) which you seem to cite, "Operationally, Prolog's execution strategy can be thought of as a generalization of function calls in other languages, one difference being that multiple clause heads can match a given call. **In that case,** [emphasis mine] the system creates a choice-point, unifies the goal with the clause head of the first alternative, and continues with the goals of that first alternative." Read Sterling and Shapiro's "The Art of Prolog" for a far more complete discussion of the subject.

Comment: What makes you believe that the term "chronological backtracking" is weird?

Comment: @false Only because it puts emphasis on _time_, instead of the position. When things are in a defined order already, suggesting that they are ordered in time, too, does not add any useful information (or, as usual, I don't actually understand what is meant, exactly, hence the confusion).

Comment: Chronological means: you can backtrack back in a certain fashion: You backtrack always back to the **youngest** choicepoint. You cannot chose any choicepoint (as in or-parallel approaches) you get only one.

Comment: @false Thank you for the explanation. After googling a bit, I sort of got it. I just found it confusing to talk about the **age** of a choicepoint, when its position in the search tree, defined by the structure of the predicate creating it, does the exactly same job, without involving time in any way (Admittedly the term has more meaning in the context of different approaches to choosing choicepoints.)

Comment: @Boris that's actually quite an established term with well understood meaning. There were languages that tried to be smarter in their retracing of their steps, on failure - they tried to re-make the "most-promising" choice, not the most recent. Prolog designers decidedly stopped trying to be super-smart about it, and implemented the left-to-right, top-down strategy. Good for language implementation, isn't automatically better or worse for your domain. -- about "time": it is determined by a goal's "place" because Prolog's resolution strategy is fixed. *Running* a program *creates* "time".

Answer (score 3):

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation) I got

> In eager evaluation, an expression is evaluated as soon as it is bound to a variable.

Then I think there are 2 levels - at user level (our predicates) Prolog is not eager.
But it is at 'system' level, because variables are implemented as efficiently as possible.

Indeed, attributed variables are implemented to be lazy, and are rather 'orthogonal' to 'logic' Prolog variables.